# Throttling Handler for OData API

Tags: odata

I have an OData API which is working fine and returns the expected result. When I add `ThrottlingHandler()` derived from `DeletgatingHandler` with `OData Route` it throws

**error:**

> 500 Internal Server Error

The response does not contain any data.

**OData Route:**

```
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Session>(ControllerResources.Session);
    var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

    var pathHandler = new DefaultODataPathHandler();
    var routingConventions = ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault();
    var routeConstraint = new ODataPathRouteConstraint(pathHandler, model, Area,   routingConventions);

    var route = new ODataRoute(ControllerResources.ODataRoutePrefix,  routeConstraint, new HttpRouteValueDictionary(), new HttpRouteValueDictionary(),    new HttpRouteValueDictionary(),  **new ThrottlingHandler()**);

    routes.Add(Area, route);
```

**ThrottlingHandler() : DelegateHandler**

```
    returnValue = base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

    return returnValue;
```

Comment: I limit issue to [ODataFormatting] property. DelegatingHandler.sendAsync is returning HttpResponseMessage and my OData API is using [ODataFormatting] property. But I need to use this property in order to make my data OData supportive.

Comment: Any suggestions how can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

@Sukhvinder Uppal

I think this is resolved after syncing. Right?